# Entity Framework Relations With Fluent Api

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framwork 6.0.2 and I'm trying to create a relationship one to one with User and UserLogged with Id's. I'm using EntityTypeConfiguration (Fluent API) and I'm not getting. See below my code:

```
public class User
{

    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }        

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public String Login { get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
}

public class UserLogged
{

    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }

    public String ComputerName { get; set; }

    public String AddressIp { get; set; }

    public String AddressMac { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }        
}

public class UserLoggedMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserLogged>
{
    public UserLoggedMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(u => u.UserId);
        this.HasRequired(u => u.User).WithOptional(u => u.UserId);            
    }
}
```

Thank you much.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You say that "you're not getting", but you don't say what you're not getting.  It would help other users trying to answer the question if you showed why what you've written here doesn't work.  Error message?  Unexpected behavior?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I will be more specific. I can't to mapped the UserLogged to make UserLoggerId a Foreign Key and Primary Key.